# Kind of like header files, can I separate some definitions in C#?

Tags: c#

In short, I'm hoping to achieve a kind of barebones structure in one place and implement/define in another. I want to better "see" the interconnectedness without all the functionality clouding it up mostly for design discussions, explanations, etc. I could do this with inheritance, but I really don't want to change all the names of everything just to achieve this. Is this a thing somehow?

```cs
// Simple File for seeing relationships between classes
public class AllMyObjectTypes // A class because it will be its own object with functionality below all this structural stuff
{
    public class Thing1
    {
        public Thing2[] things2;
        public Thing3[] things3;
    }

    public class Thing2[]
    {
        public int version;
        public Thing1[] thing1Utilizers;
    }

    public class Thing3[]
    {
        public string Title;
    }
}


// Complicated file for doing all the hard work for Thing1 with all the internal variables to make it happen.
public class Thing1 : Thing1 // Implement itself somehow?
{
    // Stuff I want to use and define but not cloud the structure above
    private int[] internalStuff; 
    private string moreInternalStuff;

    public void UsefulFunctionButWantSeparated()
    {
        // Hundreds of lines of code clouding junk up
    }
}
```

Comment: While I would not advice this, you can use `partial` classes. This will allow you to spread the full implementation/declaration of a class over multiple files. Do note that whatever you put into one file will still have to be a full implementation of that whatever. For instance, if you decide to declare properties in one file, you still need to provide the full property declaration and implementation in that file. You can't say `public int Value { get; set; }` in one file and then expand get/set in another file to provide code. To do *that* you either need inheritance or interfaces.

Comment: [Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface)

Comment: You want an interface as stated twice. You can use an interface & later use an implementation of that interface to contain your details

Comment: Can someone maybe provide an example in an answer? I'm struggle to get it to work. I get an error that interfaces can't have fields which kinda ruins it. I want fields moreso than functions.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Instead of fields use properties.

Comment: This might be 99% of what I'm looking for. The get/set scares me but it seems like I can just use it all like normal :-P. I can't seem to define an enum within the interface though, eh? Might just have to do without?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, Partial is exactly what I wanted. Makes things WAY easier! Add an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: You could also use a region. I don't use them much, but they're handy if you want something in the class but hidden. I'm saying that without understanding the question at all. But if partial classes solve it, then maybe regions will too.

Comment: @ScottHannen if you're referring to collapsible sections of code, that is potential workaround, but I'd rather have it all open and editable while still being separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial Classes is exactly what I was looking for, but it did require that I don't nest within another class. Unless maybe I made that partial too...? But either way, this gets me closest to my goal

```cs
// Simple File for seeing relationships between classes
//public class AllMyObjectTypes // A class because it will be its own object with functionality below all this structural stuff
//{
    public partial class Thing1
    {
        public Thing2[] things2;
        public Thing3[] things3;
    }

    public partial class Thing2[]
    {
        public int version;
        public Thing1[] thing1Utilizers;
    }

    public partial class Thing3[]
    {
        public string Title;
    }
//}


// Complicated file for doing all the hard work for Thing1 with all the internal variables to make it happen.
public partial class Thing1 // More implementation
{
    // Stuff I want to use and define but not cloud the structure above
    private int[] internalStuff; 
    private string moreInternalStuff;

    public void UsefulFunctionButWantSeparated()
    {
        // Hundreds of lines of code [no longer] clouding junk up
    }
}
```

Comment: A partial class will technically solve the problem, it introduces unnecessary obfuscation. I wouldn't recommend using partial classes in anything large scale unless you can describe a technical reason to need a partial class. This is a useful post https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/71494/why-use-partial-classes

Comment: I think in my case it's not really adding much obfuscation since all it is doing is defining the existence of a few internal variables which are easily seen with a mouse-over. If I were defining functionality in multiple places it could make it confusing, but not so much here. In fact, the point in my case is to be less obfuscated and I have a much easier time discussing my setup now.

Comment: I mean in everything you said you're technically not wrong. And what you need at the bottom line is all that matters. I think the discussion is more about philosophy and maybe belongs in software engineering anyway... I'd deny a pull request if they tried to check this in. Intuitively no one just looking at the code would understand why some properties are in one file and some are in another.

Comment: Maybe `UsefulFunctionButWantSeparated` should be put into an extension method instead

Answer (score 1):

Interface & Class declarations

```
public interface IThing
{
    IThing2[] Thing2s();
    string DoSomething();
}

public class Thing : IThing
{
    private readonly IThing2[] _thing2s = new IThing2[1] { new Thing2() };
    public IThing2[] Thing2s() => _thing2s;

    public string DoSomething()
    {
        return "MyText";
    }
}

public interface IThing2
{

}

public class Thing2 : IThing2
{

}
```

Use

```
IThing thing;
thing = new Thing();
var thing2s = thing.Thing2s();
var txt = thing.DoSomething();
```